# How to multiply matrix and vector using class Task c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

How to multiply matrix by vector using class Task?
I don't understand where exactly I can use tasks in my code. Any ideas?

```
 public static int[] matxvecTask(int[,] mat, int[] vec) //функция умножения матрицы на вектор Task
{
    Task[] tasks = new Task[4]
    {
        new Task(() => Console.WriteLine("1")),
        new Task(() => Console.WriteLine("2")),
        new Task(() => Console.WriteLine("3")),
        new Task(() => Console.WriteLine("4"))
    };
    foreach(var t in tasks)
    {
        t.Start();
    }
    Task.WaitAll(tasks);
     int[] res = new int[mat.GetLength(0)] ;

         for (int i = 0; i < mat.GetLength(0); i++)
         {
             for (int j = 0; j < mat.GetLength(1); j++)
             {
                 res[i] += mat[i, j] * vec[j];
             }
         }

     return res;
}
```

Comment: Why exactly do you want to use Tasks? Check out [parallel loops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for?view=netframework-4.8). Maybe this is what you want.

Comment: @ErikT. I did it using Parallel Loop, now I have to do it with Tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly your question is quite unclear. Anyway this code now uses a task. Make sure you use at least C# 7.1 as the used signature of the `Main()` method is not a valid entrypoint in previous language specifications.

```
internal class Program
{
    private static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[,] mat = new int[3, 3];
        int[] vec = new int[3];

        int[] result = await Task.Run(() => matxvecAsync(mat, vec));

        Console.WriteLine($"Execution of '{nameof(matxvecAsync)}()' finished");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static int[] matxvecAsync(int[,] mat, int[] vec)
    {
        int[] res = new int[mat.GetLength(0)];

        for (int i = 0; i < mat.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < mat.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                res[i] += mat[i, j] * vec[j];
            }
        }

        return res;
    }

}
```

If you want an answer of better quality you need to provide more information about your problem.

- Why do you want to use tasks?
- Do you think you would solve your actual problem with it?
- What are your requirements for this piece of code?
- Are you just curious about the [TAP (Task-based asynchronous pattern)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap)?